# Problem to find the Near By Brokers using Google API

Tags: apex

I am working on defect related to NearByBrokers. The problem is when the user enters a postel code in the search text box, the results of the search didn't contain the record on which we are doing the search.

For eg: I have created a contact named "Dummy Test" with the postel code as "E14 9GE" and selected a company named "Test1" with the same postel code i.e "E14 9GE". When I clicked on the "NearByBroker" button of the contact with the postel code as "E14 9GE" and search. I am getting the results. But the result didn't contain the "Dummy Test" as a first record.

In the debug log I had found that in the SOQL query we are not getting this record and that is the reason why this record is not available in the result. Given below is the query:

```
SELECT Id,Work_Street__c,Work_City__c,Work_Postal_Code__c,OtherStreet,OtherCity,OtherPostalCode,OtherState,OtherCountry,Other__c,Is_Active__c,HomePhone,MobilePhone,OtherPhone,
Gender__c,Salutation,Name,FirstName,MiddleName__c,LastName,Preferred_Name__c,Email,Birthdate,Country__c,Correspondence__c,Network_Principal_Company_Name__c,
Network_Principal_FRN_Number__c,AccountId,Company_FRN_Number__c,MailingStreet,MailingCity,MailingPostalCode,MailingState,MailingCountry,Phone,Broker_Ref__c,
At_Risk_Indicator__c,Location__Latitude__s,Location__Longitude__s,Last_Activity_Date__c,Company_Location__Latitude__s,Company_Location__Longitude__s,
Personal_Location__Latitude__s,Personal_Location__Longitude__s,Work_Location__Longitude__s,Work_Location__Latitude__s, Account.Name 
FROM Contact 
WHERE DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION(51.49884230000001,-0.0143269), 'mi') < 5.0 
ORDER BY Location__Latitude__s ASC
```

Can anybody please suggest ?

Thanks
Madhuri